# Replacement for GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA in core profile?

Tags: macos, opengl

I am making a game engine and only recently updated it to core profile OpenGL. After doing so I discovered that GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, which I use for font textures, is deprecated. After replacing it with GL_RG, I have the areas that should be alpha red, and the area that should be white green!

[GL_RG result...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Si06.png)

This of course is not what I want! Is there any way to swizzle mask this back to the way I want it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the answer by just fooling around with the swizzle mask values, and here is how I reverted it back to normal:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, GL_RED);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_RED);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_GREEN);
```

This made it look perfectly normal again!

Comment: Wouldn't it have been ways easier to do that in the shader?

Comment: @BDL: Sure, if you want to write a special purpose shader code path for monochromatic textures. Setting a swizzle mask on the texture object allows for shader reuse and keeps the format specific stuff localized.

Answer (score 0):

If you shader, change  `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` by `GL_RG` uses things like this:

```
rgba = texture(sampler, TextCoord)
```

then instead of doing

```
rgb.a
```

you do

```
rgb.g
```

I guess