# SOIL2 don't load grayscale texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, soil

I am new to OpenGL and am learning it at the moment.

Using SOIL2, I'm loading a texture and trying to render it on the screen. I load the texture like this:

```cpp
GLuint texture;
texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(("resources/textures/" + fileName + ".png").c_str(),
   SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, //Problem
   SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
   SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);
```

The problem is that when I try to load a texture with SOIL_LOAD_AUTO or SOIL_LOAD_LA, I get a black square. That being said, if I use SOIL_LOAD_RGBA, the grayscale texture is displayed.

Internet searches turn up nothing, and I'm inclined to believe that I don't understand how the "Greyscale" mode works.

At the moment my code looks like this (Yes, it's a bit wrong, but right now I'm trying to understand how OpenGL buffers, texture loading and shaders work, so I didn't do everything perfectly):

Render:

```cpp
void Render::runGame() {
    logger->info("Running content rendering...");

    glfwShowWindow(window);

    World world(width, height, &logger);

    GLfloat data[] = {
        0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, //Top left
        0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, //Bottom left
        0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, //Top right
        0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f  //Bottom right
    };
    GLubyte edata[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };

    world.getNormalizedCoord(0, height, 0, data);
    world.getNormalizedCoord(0, 0, 8, data);
    world.getNormalizedCoord(width, height, 16, data);
    world.getNormalizedCoord(width, 0, 24, data);

    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    GLuint EBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    GLuint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(edata), edata, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) (2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) (6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArray(NULL);
    
    Shader shader = Shader("tile", &logger);
    shader.create();
    
    Texture texture = Texture("tile", &logger);
    texture.create();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (texture.use() && shader.use()) {
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
            glBindVertexArray(NULL);
        }

        shader.free();
        texture.free();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    destroy();
}
```

Texture class:

```cpp
//Constructor...

Texture::~Texture() noexcept { glDeleteTextures(1, &texture); }

void Texture::create() {
    if (hasLogger()) logger->info("Loading «" + fileName + "» texture...");

    if (isCreated()) {
        if (hasLogger()) logger->warn("Attempt to create texture «" + fileName + "» that is already created");
        return;
    }

    GLuint texture;
    texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(("resources/textures/" + fileName + ".png").c_str(),
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, //Problem
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB);

    if (texture == 0) {
        if (hasLogger()) logger->fatal("Failed to create texture «" + fileName + "»: " + SOIL_last_result());
        return;
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    this->texture = texture;
    created = true;
}

GLuint Texture::getTexture() const noexcept { return texture; }

bool Texture::use() const {
    if (!isCreated()) {
        if (hasLogger()) logger->warn("Texture «" + fileName + "» using before creating");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        return true;
    }
}

void Texture::free() const noexcept { glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL); }

bool Texture::isCreated() const noexcept { return created; }
bool Texture::hasLogger() const noexcept { return logger != nullptr; }
```

Verticies shader:

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;
out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    fragColor = color;
    fragTexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core

in vec4 fragColor;
in vec2 fragTexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D fragTexture;

void main() {
    color = texture(fragTexture, fragTexCoord);
}
```

Texture:
[image]

And my result with with SOIL_LOAD_AUTO or SOIL_LOAD_LA
[image]

The result I want to get, at the moment it's only possible with SOIL_LOAD_RGBA:
[image]

I really do not understand what's the matter, what could be the reason for such strange behavior?

P.S. My OpenGL version is 3.3 core profile and forward compatibility

#### SOLUTION:

I followed the advice from the accepted answer and abandoned SOIL. I used std_image instead, and loaded the texture into OpenGL correctly. My render code hasn't changed, and the texture loading code now looks like this:

```cpp
void Texture::create() noexcept {
    if (hasLogger()) logger->info("Loading «" + fileName + "» texture...");

    if (isCreated()) {
        if (hasLogger()) logger->warn("Attempt to create texture «" + fileName + "» that is already created");
        return;
    }

    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); //flip y for opengl render correctly
    stbi_uc* data = stbi_load(("resources/textures/" + fileName + ".png").c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

    if (data) {
        GLuint texture;

        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        GLenum format;
        switch (nrChannels) {
            case 1: { //L
                format = GL_RED;
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, GL_RED); //Texture swizzle parameters
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_RED); //for correct store and render
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED); //image with different channels
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_ONE);
                break;
            }
            case 2: { //LA
                format = GL_RG;
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, GL_RED);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_RED);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_GREEN);

                for (int i = 0; i < 2 * width * height; i += 2) { //Multiply alpha
                    data[i] = (data[i] * data[i + 1] + 128) >> 8;
                }

                break;
            }
            case 3: default: { //RGB
                format = GL_RGB;
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, GL_RED);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_GREEN);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_BLUE);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_ONE);
                break;
            }
            case 4: { //RGBA
                format = GL_RGBA;
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_R, GL_RED);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_GREEN);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_BLUE);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_A, GL_ALPHA);

                for (int i = 0; i < 4 * width * height; i += 4) { //Multiply alpha
                    data[i + 0] = (data[i + 0] * data[i + 3] + 128) >> 8;
                    data[i + 1] = (data[i + 1] * data[i + 3] + 128) >> 8;
                    data[i + 2] = (data[i + 2] * data[i + 3] + 128) >> 8;
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, format == GL_RGBA || format == GL_RG ? GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE : GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, format == GL_RGBA || format == GL_RG ? GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE : GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL);


        stbi_image_free(data);

        this->texture = texture;
        created = true;
    }
    else {
        if (hasLogger()) logger->fatal("Failed to create texture «" + fileName + "»");
    }
}
```

I made loading four texture types like Luminous, Luminous/Alpha, RGB, RGBA. For this I had to use GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE. In addition, I did not find an analogue of SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA, and without it, transparent textures look a little different than I expected. So I added code to handle this detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of images that may be loaded (force_channels) ([SOIL.h](https://github.com/kbranigan/Simple-OpenGL-Image-Library/blob/master/src/SOIL.h#LC47)).

- **SOIL_LOAD_AUTO** (`=0`) leaves the image in whatever format it was found.
- **SOIL_LOAD_LA** (`=2`) forces the image to load as Luminous with Alpha
- **SOIL_LOAD_RGBA** (`=4`) forces the image to load as Red Green Blue Alpha

In the function [SOIL_internal_create_OGL_texture](https://github.com/kbranigan/Simple-OpenGL-Image-Library/blob/master/src/SOIL.c#LC990), line [1187](https://github.com/kbranigan/Simple-OpenGL-Image-Library/blob/master/src/SOIL.c#LC1187), you'll see, that SOIL uses the `GL_LUMINANCE` and `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` symbols if the channel count is `1` or `2`.

The only problem is, that `GL_LUMINANCE` and `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` are unknown to the current OpenGL version (4.6). In Legacy OpenGL and OpenGL ES on the other hand, `glTexImage2D` will recognize those symbols as `format` argument.

**Solution**:

- use Legacy OpenGL or OpenGL ES,
- save the image file as rgb(a) (so you can use `SOIL_LOAD_AUTO`, if you're using current OpenGL),
- force `SOIL_LOAD_RGB(A)` (for all OpenGL versions) or
- abandon SOIL and use [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb) (which SOIL is based on) and create the texture(s) yourself (which, if you want to learn OpenGL, is the better approach anyway).

**Example** (using stb_image):

```
//if you want to flip the texture data vertically
//stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);

const char *filename = ""; //path of image file
int width;        //width of image
int height;       //height of image
int num_channels; //number of channels in image

//since we're interested in the channel count, set last param to 0
stbi_uc *data = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &num_channels, 0);

//num_channels to texture `format`
GLenum format;
switch (num_channels) {
    case 1: format = GL_RED;  break; //STBI_grey
    case 2: format = GL_RG;   break; //STBI_grey_alpha
    case 3: format = GL_RGB;  break; //STBI_rgb
    case 4: format = GL_RGBA; break; //STBI_rgb_alpha
    //default: something went wrong
}

//texture name
GLuint tex;

//generate texture name
glGenTextures(1, &tex);

//bind the texture to a specific texture target
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

//create the texture image
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
    0,      //mipmap level 0,
            //use glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D) for automation
    format, //internal format, does not have to be the same as format, but
            //then you have to consider the conversation effects
    width,  
    height, 
    0,      //no border
    format, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, //stbi_uc -> unsigned char
    data
);

//set texture params (min, mag, wrap_s, wrap_t)
//glTexParameteri...

//unbind texture from target
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//free image data
stbi_image_free(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did consider abandoning SOIL, but since my main goal at the moment is to learn the process, I fundamentally wanted to make it work as expected) Maybe I'm just a "stubborn fool")

You mentioned obsolete versions of OpenGL. I'm using OpenGL 3.3, is it the same for this version? Also, I'm wondering how can I store a "greyscale" texture using the new versions of OpenGL?

Comment: Also, I'm using Soil2 and it says that core profile features of OpenGL are supported...

Comment: So, I found something on this topic.

Unfortunately, in my version of OpenGl, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA and similar things are not supported either.

I don't want to use a compatibility profile, if only because I definitely need to look into core profile more.

When I get home, I'll try to take your advice using stb_image.

Also I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173075/replacement-for-gl-luminance-alpha-in-core-profile

It seems to be just my case.

Comment: From looking into the source (`SOIL2.c`), `GL_LUMINANCE(_ALPHA)` are still in use. And yes, you're right OpenGL 3.3 does not contain those symbols either.

Comment: The answer you referenced, changed the argument from `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA` to `GL_RG` and got different results, which could be corrected via swizzling. Your case is different, since it is not you who sets the parameter, it is SOIL.

Comment: IMHO, `stb_image` does one thing and does that right, loading images. You want to learn the whole process, then don't use other libs which do many things, and not right (at least in your case) on top.

Comment: Thanks again, now everything works as I expected. So far, at least --.--

I edited the question and added my final solution to it